# rest-assured jsonPath returns HashMap instead of LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, linkedhashmap, rest-assured-jsonpath

This pertains to Java.

I would like to be able to change the default behavior of how a JsonPath object returns itself when parsed from a json response so that I can still leverage the methods it comes with such as getMap(), getList(), etc. Ideally I would like all the JsonPath methods to return their Map objects as a LinkedHashMap instead of a HashMap or at the minimum have the getMap() method return as a LinkedHashMap so I can preserve key ordering.

The below response object's json key ordering matches the browser's json response:

```
Response response = given().get(urlQuery).then().extract().response();
```

However, when you attempt to grab an object or value from the response via jsonPath() then the json key ordering is all screwed up due to the fact that JsonPath methods are leveraging a HashMap instead of a LinkedHashMap behind the scenes such as the code snippet below does:

```
Map map = response.jsonPath().getMap("path.to.a.map");
```

I'm hoping the answer lies within changing the config to something, or overloading a method somewhere, etc. as I like using the rest-assured library for all my json parsing except I now need to preserve key ordering.

Aside from the response object as mentioned above, I would be content if I could at the minimum get the JsonPath methods to return the json in the correct order as shown by the below code example:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

String json = "{\"fields\":{\"field1\":1,\"field2\":2,\"field3\":3,\"field4\":\"4\"}}";

// The value of the JsonPath object stays in the correct order: {"fields":{"field1":1,"field2":2,"field3":3,"field4":"4"}}
JsonPath jsonpath = new JsonPath(json);

// When using any of the JsonPath methods the order is messed up and returns: "{field4=4, field3=3, field2=2, field1=1}"
Object map = jsonpath.getMap("fields");
```

I would like to somehow get the JsonPath methods to keep the order by leveraging LinkedHashMap types but am unsure how or where to implement this.

Comment: OOC, why do you care about key ordering in JSON? Is there a semantic difference between `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}` and `{"bar": 2, "foo": 1}` in your app? If so, why?

Comment: Great question, It's because I'm writing a test for getting the ordering of the keys and then matching them to a later exported csv that should follow the same column ordering as the api's response (but I don't want to hard code the key ordering as it can change based on what's passed in to the api call).

Comment: I'm the founder of REST Assured and I don't think there's a way to configure this. But perhaps you can add it as an issue on the issue tracker (https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/issues) and I'll see what I can do.